# Returns not empty rows checking in join query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Im using codeigniter CI, trying to load some record from a database table

```
$this->db->select("pb.product_title,pb.product_id,pi.image,cd.company_name");
$this->db->from('ec_product_basic_info as pb');
$this->db->join('ec_product_package as pp','pp.product_id=pb.product_id','left');
$this->db->join('ec_comp_detail_general','cd.company_general_id=pb.company_general_id','left');  
$this->db->join('ec_product_image','pi.product_id=pb.product_id','left');
```

for some case ec_product_image has no record for corresponding product id. I need only product that has only product image,  is any option to check it, with in join query ???

Comment: if you only want products with product image, remove the `LEFT JOIN` from the `'ec_product_image'` table to make it a normal `JOIN` like this : `$this->db->join('ec_product_image','pi.product_id=pb.product_id');` forcing the need of an image

Comment: @PrateikDarji not working

Comment: @claudio its working, thanks alot

Comment: @claudio is any option to show no images records?